# Не подключается pgAdmin4 к postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin4

Установил PostgreSQL и pgAdmin4, но при подключение выдает такую ошибку
**connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL password authentication failed for user "postgres"**.

Comment: а вы перевели сообщение об ошибке? что она говорит?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Пишет ошибку аунтификации по паролю

Comment: уже хорошо. получается, что пароль или username неверны. осталось найти верные. попробуйте `postgres` как пароль и юзернейм